# Generate Swagger JSON for an Apex REST API?

Tags: apexrest

I've been finding documentation on how Salesforce can utilize API JSON generated by Swagger to generate code and implement APIs that way, but what I haven't been able to find is if it is possible to take an Apex REST API and generate this Swagger JSON from it for documentation purposes.

I have tried to use Swagger's tools to do this but no URL for my endpoint works that I have tried. Any help or guidance on how to accomplish this (if possible) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is feature is being Piloted starting with the Spring '21 release:
[Spring '21 Release Notes - Open API 3.0 Specification (Pilot)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_openapi_spec_pilot.htm&type=5&release=230)